# How to classify a set of samples via a continuous feature?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, classification

For example I got below table which is simply a coarse distribution for 20 persons over their age

**age         count of person**

- 2                              1
- 5                              5
- 8                              2
- 10                           3
- 15                           1
- 16                           2
- 17                           1
- 20                           4
- 21                          1

Then by using the same dataset, I could build another 'better' table .

**age             count of person**

- 10-                  8
- 10s                  7
- 20+                 5

In fact , I could make more tables which contains different age range combination  by using the same dataset.

Now I wonder how could I find the best combinations. The possible "goodness functions" we could use to measure  if the combination is good or not might come by following three principles:

- There should not be too many or too little classes
- Ranges of classes should not vary too much.
- Distribution should be smooth enough, that is ,number of items covered by each class should not vary too much.

Since this question represents a situation which is just general enough to describe a  kind of specific problems , some sophisticated solutions to it should have already been there . But I failed to find them. Anyone could give some suggestions please?

I have go through some classification algorithm like PCA, k-mean or "max entropy based algorithm" but seems they are just too general to cover this specific problem by following all of the above three principles.

Comment: How does this statistics question relate to programming? I'm not sure it would be 100% appropriate, but have you considered **[math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)**?

Comment: What is the purpose of this clustering? Usually, you cluster into predefined groups and the cases where the numbers for some class are very different from the others are interesting.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to take ~ sqrt(N) bins if you have N data.

Comment: I believe you should formulate requirements more precisely - "too little", "too much", "smooth enough", etc. aren't good conditions for am algorithm. Can you provide us with a background, what this task is part of?

Comment: @stakx: in general, such a question may have a purely algorithmic solution (some data structure or some well-known algorithm), so actually it relate to programming. However, it also relates to math and statistics, so if nobody provides good answer I also suggest to try on the [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). But first let's look at problem background and possible algorithmic solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

Construct an evaluation function:

```
double goodness(double firstThreshold, double bucketWidth, int numBuckets)
```

which returns a goodness score based on your principles.  I would then brute force a number of combinations of parameters and pick the combination with the best goodness score.  If we try 4-10 values for each parameter then brute force will work, and probably give you nice round numbers for the cutoffs.  If you want to get more sophisticated or have it run faster then you can try other search methods like hill-climbing, beam search or simulated annealing but I think that might be overkill for your situation.